# Displaying 64-bit register in ASM

Tags: linux, fasm

This is my first attempt in 64-bit assembly under Linux. I am using FASM.

I am converting a 64-bit register hex value to string. It is working fine until it reaches the final digit. I can't figure out exactly what's wrong with my code. Maybe there is something about 64-programming that I don't know or with the syscall (I am a linux noob as well)

```
format ELF64 executable 3
entry start

segment readable executable
start:
    mov rax,3c5677h ;final '7' is not displayed
    push rax
    call REG
    ;call line

    xor edi,edi     ;exit
    mov eax,60
    syscall

;---------------------------------- 
REG:push rbp        ;stack frame setup  
    mov rbp,rsp
    sub rsp,8       ;space for local char
    mov rax,[rbp+16];arg
    lea r9,[rsp-8]  ;local char
    mov rcx,16      ;divisor
    mov rsi,16      ;16 hex digits for register 
.begin:             ;get the digit
    xor rdx,rdx       ;by division
    div rcx         ;of 16   
    push rdx        ;from back to front
    dec rsi
    test rsi,rsi
    jz .disp
    jmp .begin
.disp:              ;convert and display digit
    inc rsi          
    pop rax         ;In reverse order
    add rax,30h     ;convert digit to string
    cmp rax,39h     ;if alpha
    jbe .normal
    add rax,7       ;add 7
.normal:
    mov [r9],rax    ;copy the value
    push rsi        ;save RSI for syscall 
    mov rsi,r9      ;address of char
    mov edx,1       ;size
    mov edi,1       ;stdout
    mov eax,1       ;sys_write
    syscall
    pop rsi         ;restore RSI for index
    cmp rsi,16
    je .done
    jmp .disp
.done:  
    add rsp,8       ;stack balancing
    pop rbp 
    ret
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like the perfect job for the debugger.

Comment: I am a linux noob as well. May take me some time to learn something like the gdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem printing the last digit comes from how you load r9.  If on entry, rsp was 100.  You subtract 8 (rsp = 92), then load r9 with rsp - 8 (r9 = 84).  Presumably you meant r9 to 100, so try changing that to:

```
lea r9, [rsp+8]
```

For a more efficient solution, how about something more like this (assumes value in rbx):

```
    mov r9, 16 ; How many digits to print
    mov rsi, rsp ; memory to write digits to
    sub rsp, 8 ; protect our stack

    mov edx, 1 ; size is always 1
    mov edi, 1 ; stdout is always 1

.disp:
    rol rbx, 4 ; Get the next nibble
    mov cl, bl ; copy it to scratch
    and cl, 15 ; mask out extra bits
    add cl, 0x30 ; Convert to char
    cmp cl, 0x39 ; if alpha
    jbe .normal
    add cl, 7 ; Adjust for letters

.normal:
    mov [rsi], cl ; copy the value
    mov eax, 1 ; sys_write
    syscall ;  overwrites rcx, rax, r11
    dec r9 ; Finished a digit
    jnz .disp ; Are we done?
    add rsp, 8 ; Done with the memory
```

Comment: I really appreciate the alternative David. That nibble/ROL method is cool - get rid of DIV by 16. But I still need to know what's wrong with my code. Linux, syscall, ELF and 64-bit are very new to me.

Comment: In your original code, printing out 16 bytes would require 32 pushes and 32 pops (mine has zero).  This alternative also has no redundant loading of edx & edi, no double jmps, only 1 loop, etc.  But you are right, I didn't answer your original question.  I will edit the answer to add that.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the bug and for the much better alternative code. Actually I was trying to convert a 32-bit proc to 64-bit and see how it goes. I didn't expect 64-bit asm to be so different with all those ABI, red zone, calling conventions etc. That effectively puts me back into total noob position. LOL